# statements not getting executed within a function, executing independently

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have run into a strange issue (I am new to R). I have tried creating a function as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
median_confidence_interval <- function(x) {
  quart_list<-c()
  return_data<-data.frame(lower_ci=0,median=0,upper_ci=0)
  for(i in 1:1000){ 
    y<-x[as.integer(runif(length(x), min = 1, max = length(x) + 1))]
    median<-median(y)
    quart_list=c(quart_list,median)
  }
  return_data$median<-median(quart_list)
  return_data$lower_ci<-quantile(quart_list,probs=0.025)
  return_data$upper_ci<-quantile(quart_list,probs=0.975)
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + geom_density(aes(x=x)) + geom_density(aes(x=quart_list)) 
  p <- p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = return_data$median, color='red'))
  p <- p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = return_data$lower_ci, color='blue'))
  p <- p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = return_data$upper_ci, color='green')) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(x),max(x)))
  png("density_confidence_internal.png")
  plot(p)
  dev.off()
  return_data
}
```

In this code I am simply trying to create a plot and save it. Though I am able to execute each of these statements independently, outside the function, but not inside the function. The function compiles without errors but while running the function it says 'quart_list' not found.
If `quart_list` and `return_data` are present in the workspace, then I am able to execute the function and get the result. When I clear the workspace and execute the function, I run into the same error while running (not compiling).

Another issue is that when I call the function `median_confidence_interval(x)`, it expects me to only provide 'x' as the argument, it doesn't take something like `median_confidence_interval(possum$earconch)`. Why could that be?

Would someone please be able to point me in some direction?

Comment: Can you include the text of the errors as well as a bit of your data `x`.  Also, assigning `median <- median(y)` isn't the best practice since you run the risk of clobbering a user defined function.

Comment: I think you should debug that for-loop first. It looks like you are a refugee from a line-oriented macro language like SAS or SPSS. Row indexing needs to be explicit inside for-loops in R.

Comment: @DWin-you are damn right, I have some experience in C# and python, not SAS, SPSS though. Totally new to R and find it weird, but still trying to learn. About the question that I asked, the exact same code works on another system(MAC). I am not sure if this is a common problem with R, but I have noticed bits n pieces working at one system and not working on another. Quite strange !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment evaluation of `ggplot` objects is a little mysterious.  However, if you remember that `ggplot` wants `data.frames` to be passed to the `data` argument and the values in `aes` should be columns of the `data.frame` you'll generally avoid issues.

To debug things like this, I find it helpful to insert print statements into the function to sort out how far through it I get. (see the commented lines)

Adjusting your function accordingly gives:

```
median_confidence_interval <- function(x) {
  quart_list<-c()
  return_data<-data.frame(lower_ci=0,median=0,upper_ci=0)
  for(i in 1:1000){ 
    y<-x[as.integer(runif(length(x), min = 1, max = length(x) + 1))]
    median<-median(y)
    # print ('inside for loop')
    quart_list=c(quart_list,median)
  }

  # print('past for loop')
  return_data$median<-median(quart_list)
  return_data$lower_ci<-quantile(quart_list,probs=0.025)
  return_data$upper_ci<-quantile(quart_list,probs=0.975)

  # print('start of ggplot code')
  foo=data.frame(q=quart_list, x=x)
  p <- ggplot()
  p <- p + geom_density(data=foo, aes(x=x)) + geom_density(data=foo, aes(x=q)) 
  # print('past first quart_list reference in ggplot')
  p <- p + geom_vline(data=return_data, aes(xintercept = median, color='red'))
  p <- p + geom_vline(data=return_data, aes(xintercept = lower_ci, color='blue'))
  p <- p + geom_vline(data=return_data, aes(xintercept = upper_ci, color='green')) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(x), max(x)))
  png("/tmp/density_confidence_internal.png")
  plot(p)
  dev.off()
  return_data
}
```

Also, I think @DWin has a good point in his comment!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..the exact same code works on another system(MAC). I am not sure if this is a common problem with R, but I have noticed bits n pieces of R code working at one system and not working on another. Quite strange !!